# Keeping lines in PDF after export in QGIS 3.4?

Tags: qgis-3, line, export, pdf

I have regularly this problem: when I export lines from QGIS to Illustrator with a `.pdf` (or even `.svg`), my lines are destroyed in several lines.

Is there a way to keep my lines unbroken?

[image: Line in QGIS, then lines in AI]

Comment: There is some improvements coming to QGIS soon. https://north-road.com/2019/09/03/qgis-3-10-loves-geopdf/ "checkbox is ticked when creating a Geospatial PDF output, then QGIS will automatically include all the geometry and attribute information"

Comment: @Mapperz I think that comment could be posted as an answer. As far as I know there's currently no solution to this problem.

Comment: This article is about Qgis 3.10. Does it mean that the improvement has been delayed ?

Comment: 3.10 is the upcoming release, expected here shortly at the end of the week (2019-10-25)
https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html

The PDF improvements Nyall mentions are currently in the nightly builds via OSGeo4W, and should be present in the weekly snapshot builds as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up and Coming **QGIS 3.10** has a potential solution:

[image]

> "Geospatial PDFs can now be created either by exporting the main QGIS
>   map canvas, or by creating and exporting a custom print layout. For
>   instance, when you select the “Save Map as PDF” option from the main
>   QGIS window, you’ll see a new group of Geospatial PDF related options:
>
> At its most basic, Geospatial PDF is a standard extension to the PDF
>   format which allows for vector spatial datasets to be embedded in PDF
>   files. If the **“Include vector feature information”** checkbox is ticked
>   when creating a Geospatial PDF output, then QGIS will automatically
>   include all the geometry and attribute information from features
>   visible within the page. So if we export a simple map to PDF, we’ll
>   get an output file which looks just like any old regular PDF map
>   output…"

Credit and Source (including screenshot)
https://north-road.com/2019/09/03/qgis-3-10-loves-geopdf/